# How to convert string to bool

Tags: c#, string, variables, boolean

```
private void okButton_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string city; //holds the city name
  if (cityListBox.SelectedIndex != -1) {
    //Get the selected item
    city = cityListBox.SelectedItem.ToString ();

    //determine the time zone
    if (city) {
      if (city == "Honolulu")
        timeZoneLabel.Text = "Hawaii-Aleutian";

      else if (city == "San Francisco")
        timeZoneLabel.Text = "pacific";

      else if (city == "Denver")
        timeZoneLabel.Text = "Mountain";

      else if (city == "Minneapolis")
        timeZoneLabel.Text = "Central";

      else if (city == "New York")
        timeZoneLabel.Text = "Eastern";
    }

  } else
    //No city was selected
    MessageBox.Show ("Select a city");
}
```

Right under the "//determine the time zone" the "city" in the parenthesis keeps coming up with an error saying it cant convert string to bool. What am i missing?

Comment: `city` must be a string?  But `if` requires a condition which equates to a bool.  `if "Moscow"` is gibberish

Comment: Look at what the method [string.IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.8) can do for you

Comment: _"What am i missing?"_ -- that depends on what you think the statement `if (city)` should do in the first place. Since such a statement is not valid, and since there are a variety of ways to interpret from a human-comprehension point of view, your question is unclear. Most likely, you should just omit the statement altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Your outer if-stmt is unneeded unless you mean to check for null or empty, in which case the following would do:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(city)) {
      if (city == "Honolulu")
        timeZoneLabel.Text = "Hawaii-Aleutian";

      else if (city == "San Francisco")
        timeZoneLabel.Text = "pacific";

      else if (city == "Denver")
        timeZoneLabel.Text = "Mountain";

      else if (city == "Minneapolis")
        timeZoneLabel.Text = "Central";

      else if (city == "New York")
        timeZoneLabel.Text = "Eastern";
    }
```

Comment: Should use String's "Equals" method (string1.Equals(string2)) when comparing strings, since it the == sign compares pointers in strings instead of the actual string data.

Comment: @MichaelYochpaz that's the case in Java (I think) but not C#. == is overloaded to compare for string equality.

Comment: Either way, my answer was not meant to be exhaustive, simply address OP's original question about strings and bool.

Comment: @SBFrancies You're right, that's the way it works in Java. Thought it's the same in C# but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To use an if statement you have to enter an equation that is either true or false (bool).

If it's "true" it executes the if-block commands.

If it's "false" it skips the if-block.

A few examples:

("Hello".Equals("Test")) --> False

(1 + 1 == 2) --> True

(5 < 6) --> True

(False) --> False

Entering a string in an if statement returns an error since you're not entering a true or false statement. The program doesn't know what to do with that string.

I think you might be confusing an if statement with a switch statement.

Read these MSDN docs for further information:

[if-else (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else)

[switch (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

Comment: we were originally going to use the switch statement but my instructor told us to use the if-else method